# How are WPF Buttons and TextBlock styles related?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have a custom style for my 'default' Buttons, and also created a custom style for TextBlocks. If I remove the TextBlock style entirely, everything works fine, but once the TextBlock styling is added in for some reason the Button style is used on the Button's text 'default' state. It seems like some kind of inheritance is going on here but I can't see where in the msdn docs. What's going on?

**I'm using Expression Blend 4-- and also another odd thing is that the preview in Blend looks fine, but when I RUN the application, the button styles are incorrect in their default state.** Here's the styles which seem to be conflicting:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFDFF00" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.20" ScaleX="1.20"/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="4"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Rtk;component/Fonts/#Segoe Print"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="4"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Rtk;component/Fonts/#Segoe Print"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

This is how I am using the Button control itself:

```
<Button Content="Button Text" FontSize="24"/>
```

(note that this fontsize is different from the size I specified in the default style, 18 - I want to override it in this button's case)

**Edit:**
The actual button entry looks like this in MainWindow.xaml, there's no other customizations other than the style changes I posed from App.xaml:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,0,0,274.226" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>
```

To illustrate what I'm seeing:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I uploaded a demo project with just the button and styles, for Blend 4. http://www.megaupload.com/?d=NG7CL1Q5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have suggested, your Button contains a Textblock created to hold the content, it is picking up the style from app.xaml, you can work around this in a few ways, here are a couple:

Put an explicit textblock into your button, and apply no style:

```
  <Button Margin="272,192,277,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Button" Style="{x:Null}"/>
    </Button>
```

Put a textblock into your button style, also with a null style:

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Style="{x:Null}">
                       <TextBlock.Effect>
                          <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="4"/>
                       </TextBlock.Effect>
      </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                  <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
```

Hopefully one of those 2 will work for you.

Comment: WHOA! So simple, it didn't even occur to me that you could just omit the ContentPresenter and use a binding to set the text. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 4):

Just a fast wild guess, but when the content of a button is a string, isn't it default a textblock?

Comment: Not sure, but I just realized it's not exactly like the Textblock style, so I'm not sure what's going. The font size is the same, and the drop shadow's intensity seems to be double that of the Blend preview. I only connected the problem to TextBlock because removing that style makes the Button style work correctly.

Comment: It _is_ true that a string as content of a Button will be automatically wrapped into a TextBlock - but that "implicit" TextBlock will not be influenced by a keyless Style resource.

Comment: Could this be a bug then? I'm uploading a Blend project to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking only ay the code you posted, I can't see how the TextBlock Style would in any way influence the appearance of the Buttons - *unless* the Content of the Buttons consists (directly or indirectly) of TextBlocks. Can you post a more complete code sample, possibly including the Button's XAML?

Comment: The `Content` of a `Button` is a `TextBlock` when the button is displaying text. If you wanted to display an image you'd use an `Image`. You can even make a composite button by putting a `StackPanel` in there which contains what ever you want.

Comment: I will add some more, including a screenshot to show what's going on. But the Button should just be a "default" button with that App.xaml style applied.

Comment: I put a Blend 4 example project that can be downloaded from some goofy file sharing site, if you have time to look at it. App.xaml has a comment in it before the TextBlock style where, if I remove it, the Button works perfectly... but then default TextBlocks become plain black text. I need to alter both styles.