# What are some of the more utilized WPF (optionally, including Silverlight) .NET forum/discussion sites?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

Just looking for a list of some popular WPF/Silverlight/C# sites out there for problems/troubleshooting that may need a little more back-and-forth to resolve than stackoverflow's format offers. (This is the issue that I think I should have dropped into an active "traditional" forum instead, in case anyone is able to assist: [How are WPF Buttons and TextBlock styles related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4484313/313366) , thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://windowsclient.net/Forums/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/threads/

http://forums.silverlight.net/